# Convert fraction of day to POSIX times in R

Tags: excel, datetime, r

I have a dataset that encodes a date-time into two separate variables.  Normally, I'd just paste them together inside of an `as.POSIXct` and carry on.  However, the date is provided as a string, and the time of day as a fraction of 24 hours - e.g., 12pm is 0.5, 9:30am is 0.1458333, etc.

It doesn't seem all that tricky to convert the fractional days into clock hours, but I'd prefer to use a pre-existing function if possible.  Does something like that exist in base R?  A package?

If it's any use, this is an Excel (xlsx) time field imported into R through RODBC.

EDIT
Oddly enough, upon revisiting this problem, the times are now read in as POSIXct.  Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: Haha. This sounds like my experience reading an xls file. One day I write R code to convert from a numeric Excel date, then a week later I edit the xls with some new data, and when I read it in R, the dates are text. You might play around with the cell formatting in Excel to fix it.

Comment: If you apply a cutom format to a dat-time in Excel the values that come to the text-csv files will follow that format. I'd suggest either 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM' or 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'. I don't have RODBC configured so cannot test to see if that might affect the DB transfer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIXct values are simply the number of seconds since midnight GMT 1970-01-01. (So you need to pay attention to your offset from UTC.) You can use the date part and add the number of days times 24*3600 (as.Date(dtval) to your time value * 24*3600. Gabor pointed to the article in R News (which he wrote, thank you, Gabor.)

You didn't give an example of the string. If you are getting your date as a string, then as.Date(strDate) will convert a variable "strDate" to Date class when it is in either "YYYY-MM-DD" or "YYYY/MM/DD" format. Otherwise the formatting codes are on the ?strptime page.

Once you have a POSIXct-classed variable you can just add the number of seconds. This example add 30 minutes to midnight today Feb 1, 2011 (in my time zone which is UTC-5):

```
> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2011-02-01")) +30*60
[1] "2011-01-31 19:30:00 EST"
```

And this is your time value added to midnight my time:

```
> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2011-02-01 00:00", tzone="UTC"))+3600*5 + 3600*24*timeval
[1] "2011-02-01 03:29:59 EST"
```

Comment: I don't understand this. What is `timeval` in the second code block?

Comment: It is whatever name you are assigning that value of 0.1458333 to. You multiply it by the number of seconds in a day.

Comment: Thanks.  I used this idea to to do the inverse operation:  Changing posixCT times into fractional days with:  (timeval-as.POSIXct(...))/86400.  It was very useful for doing time series analysis in other time bases than Hz, such as cycles per day.

Answer (score 7):

The [R News 4/1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf) Help Desk article has a section on reading Excel dates in R.