# Converting excel DateTime serial number to R DateTime

Tags: r

When excel tables are imported as xy points in ArcGIS I continue to lose my correct DateTime stamp for each point. Thus, I have formatted the DateTime  serial number, created the .shp, and read the .shp into R using readOGR().

Once in R I can convert to the correct date using `as.Date()` and the `origin = "1899-12-30"` argument, but the time is left out.  While I have seen examples with a sole Date, I have not seen worked examples with DateTime. I have been using `as.Date()` as well as `as.POSIXct()` but this seemingly simple task as been a bit frustrating, thus the post…

I have created a sample data set with 10 rows of the correct DateTime format as well as the excel serial number.

*Thanks Richard and thelatemail for their keen eye on an earlier hindrance.  I have corrected the data and re-posted here.

Here is my sample data

```
helpData <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, DateTime = structure(c(9L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("3/11/2011 7:55", "3/13/2011 7:55", 
"3/14/2011 0:00", "3/14/2011 10:04", "3/14/2011 7:55", "3/15/2011 19:55", 
"3/17/2011 7:55", "3/18/2011 4:04", "3/4/2011 6:00"), class = "factor"), 
ExcelNum = c(40606.25, 40613.32986, 40615.32986, 40616, 40616.41944, 
40616.32986, 40617.82986, 40619.32986, 40620.16944, 40620.16944
)), .Names = c("ID", "DateTime", "ExcelNum"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

head(helpData)
```

The DateTime is GMT. The time is a 24 hr clock (i.e. not AM/PM). I am working on Windows 7, have the most recent R, and ArcGIS 10.

The code below gets the correct Date, but the time is still missing.

```
newDateTime <- as.Date(helpData[ , "ExcelNum"], origin = "1899-12-30")
head(newDateTime)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have a look at similar topics [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868693/convert-fraction-of-day-to-posix-times-in-r) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161984/how-to-elegantly-convert-datetime-from-decimal-to-d-m-y-hms/).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your number is counting days.  Convert to seconds, and you're all set  (less a rounding error)

```
helpData[["ExcelDate"]] <- 
  as.POSIXct(helpData[["ExcelNum"]] * (60*60*24)
    , origin="1899-12-30"
    , tz="GMT")


#     ID        DateTime ExcelNum           ExcelDate
#  1   1   3/4/2011 6:00 40606.25 2011-03-04 06:00:00
#  2   2  3/11/2011 7:55 40613.33 2011-03-11 07:54:59
#  3   3  3/13/2011 7:55 40615.33 2011-03-13 07:54:59
#  4   4  3/14/2011 0:00 40616.00 2011-03-14 00:00:00
#  5   5 3/14/2011 10:04 40616.42 2011-03-14 10:03:59
#  6   6  3/14/2011 7:55 40616.33 2011-03-14 07:54:59
#  7   7 3/15/2011 19:55 40617.83 2011-03-15 19:54:59
#  8   8  3/17/2011 7:55 40619.33 2011-03-17 07:54:59
#  9   9  3/18/2011 4:04 40620.17 2011-03-18 04:03:59
#  10 10  3/18/2011 4:04 40620.17 2011-03-18 04:03:59
```

Answer (score 18):

Use the function `convertToDateTime`. It's straight forward. Here's an example:

```
library(openxlsx)
convertToDateTime(helpData$ExcelNum, origin = "1900-01-01")
```

Let me know how it works.

Comment: In the current openxlsx version, the default origin is already 1900-01-01

Answer (score 13):

The time data is still there, it's just not displayed - see:

```
as.numeric(newDateTime)
#[1] 15037.25 15044.33 15046.33 15047.00 etc etc
```

If you are wishing to work with parts of days, you are probably best using `POSIXct` representations though. To do so, you can convert to `Date`, then convert to `POSIXct`, though this does bring into play timezone issues if you want to do a direct comparison to your `DateTime` column.

```
helpData$newDate <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(helpData$ExcelNum,origin="1899-12-30"))
attr(helpData$newDate,"tzone") <- "UTC"
helpData

#   ID        DateTime ExcelNum             newDate
#1   1   3/4/2011 6:00 40606.25 2011-03-04 06:00:00
#2   2  3/11/2011 7:55 40613.33 2011-03-11 07:54:59
#3   3  3/13/2011 7:55 40615.33 2011-03-13 07:54:59
#4   4  3/14/2011 0:00 40616.00 2011-03-14 00:00:00
#5   5 3/14/2011 10:04 40616.42 2011-03-14 10:03:59
#6   6  3/14/2011 7:55 40616.33 2011-03-14 07:54:59
#7   7 3/15/2011 19:55 40617.83 2011-03-15 19:54:59
#8   8  3/17/2011 7:55 40619.33 2011-03-17 07:54:59
#9   9  3/18/2011 4:04 40620.17 2011-03-18 04:03:59
#10 10  3/18/2011 4:04 40620.17 2011-03-18 04:03:59
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way to do it using janitor and tibble packages:

```
install.packages("janitor")

install.packages("tibble")

library(tibble)

library(janitor)

excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(as.character(helpData$ExcelNum), date_system = "modern")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant:

```
library("datetimeutils")
convert_date(helpData$ExcelNum, type = "Excel")
## [1] "2011-03-04" "2011-03-11" "2011-03-13" "2011-03-14" "2011-03-14"
## [6] "2011-03-14" "2011-03-15" "2011-03-17" "2011-03-18" "2011-03-18"

convert_date(helpData$ExcelNum, type = "Excel", fraction = TRUE)
## [1] "2011-03-04 06:00:00 CET" "2011-03-11 07:54:59 CET"
## [3] "2011-03-13 07:54:59 CET" "2011-03-14 00:00:00 CET"
## [5] "2011-03-14 10:03:59 CET" "2011-03-14 07:54:59 CET"
## [7] "2011-03-15 19:54:59 CET" "2011-03-17 07:54:59 CET"
## [9] "2011-03-18 04:03:59 CET" "2011-03-18 04:03:59 CET"
```