# Formatting the time with time stamped data in R?

Tags: r

I have some time series data where I need to extract the data at certain times e.g. at `23:55:00` and `06:00:00` etc; the data is in a spreadsheet but when I load it into R the times are changed to numbers `85500`, `85800`, etc.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Could you please explain? I'm struggling to find a question in your post, for examples on how to write a good one, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-with-lubridate

Comment: Hi Kevin, the original data is supplied to me in a csv file it has 24 hour time stamps (e.g. 23:00:00) on the biological information but when I load the csv file into R it is converting the time into a single number (which I think is seconds). I would like to convert the seconds (or whatever it is) back to 24 hr time. Thank you so much......