# Convert Excel date format in a dplyr chain

Tags: r, excel, date, dplyr, tibble

I'm loading an Excel file which has a column where dates are stored as integers (43000 for example is 2017-09-22). I tried applying the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-with-lubridate) this way:

```
df = df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin = "1899-12-30"))
```

But I'm having the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: character string is not in a
standard unambiguous format. Calls: (...)
```

I searched for this problem and all results are about incorrectly specifying a string input to `as.Date` but in this situation the input is an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found the problem: the dates were somehow loaded as string instead of integers. This solved my problem:

```
df = df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(as.numeric(date), origin = "1899-12-30"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using janitor::excel_numeric_to_date can make your code slightly more concise

```
library(janitor)
df = df %>%
  mutate(date = excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(date)))
```