# Reformat Excel numeric date to R date

Tags: r, excel, date

Looking to reformat a column pulled from Excel into a dataframe that contains the numeric Excel format (e.g. 40182).

> as.date(40182, origin = "1899-12-30", format = '%b-%Y')

Returns:

[1] 5Jan2070

I'm looking for more along the lines of Jan-14 (short month, short year).

Being fairly new to R, I have been unable to determine what the cause of this is. Switching the origin date doesn't seem to change anything either.  Any help?

Comment: `as.Date(40182 - 25569, origin = "1970-01-01")`?

Comment: > as.date(40182 - 25569, origin = "1970-01-01", format = '%b-%y')
[1] 4Jan2000

Comment: There's the output of your code.  2 things: 1) this is an column of dates so I was hoping to have this change reflected over the enitrety & 2) the expected output of 41640 (the first number in the column) should be January of 2014.  When I input that to as.date, it returns 2Jan2074

Comment: try somthing like : `as.character(as.Date(40182, origin = "1899-12-30"), format = "%b-%y")`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `format(as.Date.numeric(40182,"1904-01-01"),"%b-%y")` or `format(as.Date(40182,"1904-01-01"),"%b-%y")`

Comment: @MKR this only changes the ouput to chr: "2Jan2074"

Comment: Change the origin to match your expectation

Comment: @Onyambu this is exactly what I needed, now I'll reflect this change over the whole data frame column.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: See the R Help Desk article in https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Excel date format to proper date with Lubridate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-with-lubridate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In excel, number 40182 gives the date 04-01-2010 when formated as date.
So I think you are looking for this:

```
format(as.Date(40182, origin = "1899-12-30"), '%b-%Y')
```

which gives:

```
[1] "Jan-2010"
```

hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
##simulated excel. I used an excel to tes tthe code though. 
a<-seq(from = as.Date(Sys.Date()), to = seq(as.Date(Sys.Date()), 
length.out = 12, by= "-1 years")[2], by = "-1 days")
a<-as.numeric(a)
a<-a+25569
a<-as.Date(as.numeric(a[1:length(a)]), origin = as.Date("1970-01-01"))

##a is in One Year of dates like your excel list. 

a<-as.numeric(a)
a<-a-25569
a<-as.Date(as.numeric(a[1:length(a)]), origin = as.Date("1970-01-01"))
a<-format(a, "%b-%y")
```

hope this helps you.