# How can I fix corrupted dates in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset as follows:

19/9/1997
22/9/1997
23/9/1997
24/9/1997
25/9/1997
26/9/1997
29/9/1997
30/9/1997

35440
35471
35499
35591
35621
35652
35683
35713

13/10/1997
14/10/1997
15/10/1997
16/10/1997
17/10/1997
20/10/1997
21/10/1997
22/10/1997
23/10/1997
24/10/1997
27/10/1997
28/10/1997
29/10/1997
30/10/1997
31/10/1997

35500
35531
35561
35592
35622
35714
35745
35775

13/11/1997
14/11/1997
17/11/1997
18/11/1997
19/11/1997
20/11/1997
21/11/1997
24/11/1997 ...

The Data that should be here are (for reproduction as requested)
19/9/1997
22/9/1997
23/9/1997
24/9/1997
25/9/1997
26/9/1997
29/9/1997
30/9/1997
10/01/1997
10/02/1997
10/03/1997
10/06/1997
10/07/1997
10/08/1997
10/09/1997
10/10/1997
13/10/1997
14/10/1997
15/10/1997
16/10/1997
17/10/1997
20/10/1997
21/10/1997
22/10/1997
23/10/1997
24/10/1997
27/10/1997
28/10/1997
29/10/1997
30/10/1997
31/10/1997
11/03/1997
11/04/1997
11/05/1997
11/06/1997
11/07/1997
11/10/1997
11/11/1997
11/12/1997
13/11/1997
14/11/1997
17/11/1997
18/11/1997
19/11/1997
20/11/1997
21/11/1997
24/11/1997

I have 5,149 rows of dates where there are numbers in places of dates. I tried fixing the missing dates with this:
ATTEMPT 1 BEFORE REVISION:

```
  rm (list = ls(all=TRUE))
    graphics.off()
    library(readxl)
    Dates <- read_excel("F:/OneDrive - University of Tasmania/Mardi Meetings/Dataset/Dates.xlsx")
    x<-Dates[,1]
    library(date)
    library(datetime)
    ans <- Reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      f1 <- as.Date(curr, "%d/%m/%Y")
      f2 <- as.Date(curr, "%m/%d/%Y")
      if (is.na(f1)) return(f2)
      if (is.na(f2)) return(f1)
      if (prev < f1 && prev < f2) return(min(f1, f2))
      if (prev < f1) return(f1)
      if (prev < f2) return(f2)
    }, x[-1], init=as.Date(x[1], "%d/%m/%Y"), accumulate=TRUE)

    as.Date(ans, origin="1970-01-01")
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
+ }, x[-1], init=as.Date(x[1], "%d/%m/%Y"), accumulate=TRUE)
Error in Reduce(function(prev, curr) { : object 'x' not found
> 
> as.Date(ans, origin="1970-01-01")
Error in as.Date(ans, origin = "1970-01-01") : object 'ans' not found
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

OK AS PER ADVICE I REVISED THE CODE  ATTEMPT 2 AFTER REVISION

```
    > rm (list = ls(all=TRUE))
    > graphics.off()
    > library(readxl)
    > Dates <- read_excel("F:/OneDrive - University of Tasmania/Mardi Meetings/Dataset/Dates.xlsx")
    > dput(head(Dates))
    structure(list(Date = c("33274", "33302", "33394", "33424", "33455", 
    "33486")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))
    > x<-Dates[[1]] 
    > library(date) 
    > library(datetime) 

    Attaching package: ‘datetime’

    The following object is masked from ‘package:date’:

        as.date

    > dates <- as.Date(x, format="%d/%m/%Y")
    > dput(head(dates))
    structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), class = "Date")
    > head(dates,10)
     [1] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
     [8] "1991-05-13" "1991-05-14" "1991-05-15"
As you can see I have lost the corrupted dates completely
```

Today on 28th I tried again

```
> rm (list = ls(all=TRUE))
> graphics.off()
> library(readxl)
> Dates <- read_excel("F:/OneDrive - University of Tasmania/Mardi Meetings/Dataset/Dates.xlsx")
> x<-Dates[[1]] 
> 
> library(date) 
> library(datetime) 

Attaching package: ‘datetime’

The following object is masked from ‘package:date’:

    as.date

> formats <- c("%m/%d/%Y", "%d/%m/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d")
> dates <- as.Date(rep(NA, length(x)))
> for (fmt in formats) {
+   nas <- is.na(dates)
+   dates[nas] <- as.Date(as.integer(x[nas], format=fmt))
+ }
Error in as.Date.numeric(as.integer(x[nas], format = fmt)) : 
  'origin' must be supplied
In addition: Warning message:
In as.Date(as.integer(x[nas], format = fmt)) : NAs introduced by coercion
> dates <- as.Date(x, format="%d/%m/%Y")
> head(dates)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
> head(dates, 10)
 [1] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
 [8] "1991-05-13" "1991-05-14" "1991-05-15"
```

Comment: Is this question about "corrupted dates" or is it about `'x' not found`? Since we don't have your data, it's rather difficult to troubleshoot that side of things. Perhaps you can provide the output from `dput(head(x))` before the call to `Reduce`?

Comment: Hi,thank you for your response. X is a vector of dates. Just before the code, on top, you will see listed dates.  They are rows in one column? As you can see, after 30/09/97 the following row is 3559. See that is why they are corrupted. The date information is collected from datastream. You have a few rows in dates format and some dates just turn to numbers. I need all the rows in dates, in order. The dates are not chronological. They represent some days in a week then some days not there. Again some days in next week.

Comment: Please don't post code  like `rm(list = ls())` in your question. We want to be able to copy and run your code without worrying that it will destroy work in progress on our computers.

Comment: @Gregor, sometimes I wonder if I should be trying code like this in an R-sandbox ... is there an easy way to temporarily shift `.GlobalEnv` out of the way? Not foolproof, but closer ... :-)

Comment: Not an easy way I know of... I sometimes keep two RStudio instances open, one for work and one for my stack overflow addiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need none of the packages you've loaded, nor do you need to use `Reduce`, as functions we're using here are naturally "vectorized".

Here's a sample of your data. (A good question includes data in an *easily* copied format such as this.)

```
x <- c("19/9/1997", "22/9/1997", "23/9/1997", "24/9/1997", "25/9/1997",
       "26/9/1997", "29/9/1997", "30/9/1997",
       "35440", "35471", "35499", "35591", "35621",
       "35652", "35683", "35713")

dates <- as.Date(x, format="%d/%m/%Y")
dates
#  [1] "1997-09-19" "1997-09-22" "1997-09-23" "1997-09-24" "1997-09-25" "1997-09-26"
#  [7] "1997-09-29" "1997-09-30" NA           NA           NA           NA          
# [13] NA           NA           NA           NA
```

Not surprisingly, the second-half of the dates are not recognized given `format="%d/%m/%Y"`. You mentioned the use of `"%m/%d/%Y"` in your question, so we can (1) do a literal second-pass for this format (un-utilized with this example, but still relevant for your work?):

```
dates[is.na(dates)] <- as.Date(x[is.na(dates)], format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

where `[is.na(dates)]` only works on the un-converted elements.

(2) If we have more than one other format, you can always use a vector of them and loop over them. (For this, I'll start over, since this loop would replace/augment the first steps above.)

```
formats <- c("%m/%d/%Y", "%d/%m/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d")
dates <- as.Date(rep(NA, length(x)))
for (fmt in formats) {
  nas <- is.na(dates)
  dates[nas] <- as.Date(x[nas], format=fmt)
}
dates
#  [1] "1997-09-19" "1997-09-22" "1997-09-23" "1997-09-24" "1997-09-25" "1997-09-26"
#  [7] "1997-09-29" "1997-09-30" NA           NA           NA           NA          
# [13] NA           NA           NA           NA
```

This still leaves us with `NA`s for the integer-looking ones. For these you need to specify the `origin=` to be able to figure it out (as well as converting to an integer). R typically works with an origin of `"1970-01-01"`, which you can confirm with

```
as.integer(Sys.Date())
# [1] 17787
Sys.Date() - 17787
# [1] "1970-01-01"
```

but Excel's default storage of dates uses an origin of `"1899-12-30"`.

[image: excel number/date]

```
### https://stackoverflow.com/q/43230470/3358272
as.Date(35440, origin = "1899-12-30")
# [1] "1997-01-10"
```

From here:

```
nas <- is.na(dates)
dates[nas] <- as.Date(as.integer(x[nas]), origin="1899-12-30")
dates
#  [1] "1997-09-19" "1997-09-22" "1997-09-23" "1997-09-24" "1997-09-25" "1997-09-26"
#  [7] "1997-09-29" "1997-09-30" "1997-01-10" "1997-02-10" "1997-03-10" "1997-06-10"
# [13] "1997-07-10" "1997-08-10" "1997-09-10" "1997-10-10"
```

(Working on the indices of only `NA` elements is relatively efficient in that it only works on and replaces the not-yet-matched entries. If there is nothing left when it gets to another call to `as.Date`, it does still call it but with an argument of length 0, with which the function works rather efficiently. I don't think adding a conditional of `if (any(nas)) ...` would help, but if there are further methods you need that might be more "expensive", you can consider it.)

Comment: `Dates <- read_excel("F:/Dates.xlsx")
x<-Dates[,1]                           
library(date)
library(datetime)
dates <- as.Date(x, format="%d/%m/%Y")` gives me the error `Error in as.Date.default(x, format = "%d/%m/%Y") 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”` . So I could not proceed further. Please advise how to move to the net block and get past this error.

Comment: R.Islam, I now see, it's obvious to me. `readxl::read_excel` returns a tibble, which is slightly different than a `data.frame`: when indexed with `[,1]`, a frame will (almost) always return a vector, a tibble will always return a (single-column) frame. Try `mtcars[,1]` versus `tbl_df(mtcars)[,1]`. In circumstances like this, *you need to look at your object* to know what is going on, where `class(x)` likely says `data.frame`, when `as.Date` only accepts vectors. (I'll say again: ***reproducible data sample***. The output from `dput(head(x))` would have made it obvious to many of us.)

Comment: But I should have seen that in the example you did provide, so this is just as much on me for not reading beyond your literal question.

Comment: So one answer is to replace `x<-Dates[,1]` with `x<-Dates[[1]]`.

Comment: > head(dates,10)
 [1] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
 [7] NA           "1991-05-13" "1991-05-14" "1991-05-15"  ......As you can see all the corrupted dates now become NAs. So how can i get the dates in place of NA. I guess this is progressing.

Comment: R.Islam, I'm not really certain any more what the underlying problem is. Is it that your function doesn't know how to deal with `data.frame`/`tibble`? Or is it that you don't know how to use `Reduce` (which is the wrong function for this, btw) to convert your column to a `Date` type? Are you still using `Date[,1]` on a `tibble`?

Comment: Indeed, I am new in r. However I tried your solution that turns corrupted dates into NAs

Comment: Look, there really is nothing more I can do until you provide reproducible data. I know you *say* that you've provided it, but you haven't. Please provide the output from `dput(head(Dates))` (by editing your question and adding it), and I'll take a look.

Comment: Edited up as you suggested. Please advise now for Block 2

Comment: @r2evans I never realized that we could use vector of formats, eye opener!

Comment: R.Islam, my code works perfectly for the sample `Dates` you included. Note that they are still `NA` at the end of the `for` loop, but the trailing cleanup (that looks for the integer-looking date strings) picks them up.

Comment: I see where there might be confusion in my answer. There are eight lines of code to use: from `formats <- c(...); dates <- as.Date(rep(NA,...)); for (fmt in formats) { ...}; nas <- is.na(dates); dates[nas] <- as.Date(as.integer(x[nas]),...)`. Don't forget those last two, they are the "clean-up" for the integer-looking strings.

Comment: Hi, what should i put in place of c(...)...what goes in place of the dots? thank you for your help

Comment: I was shortening code that is already in the answer. That first line is `formats <- c("%m/%d/%Y", "%d/%m/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d")`.

Comment: Hi, @r2evans, Please see the edited post above as per your suggestion....I am stuck

Comment: @R.Islam The main suggestion in these comments seems to be that you should post reproducible sample data. With `dput()`. So it's copy/pasteable and reflects your actual data structure. **He's asked for it at least 3 times.** If I were r2evans, I would feel pretty stuck too. If you don't know how to provide reproducible data, please [see this FAQ on making reproducible examples in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/903061). The one time you did use `dput`, it only captured integer-style dates, `"33274", "33302", "33394", "33424", "33455", "33486"`. Please find a representative subset.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry if I could not reproduce the data as you wanted. As you can see even after using dput some dates are shown in integers. My data is collected from datastream and in between dates i have these integers. These have been my problem to begin with and I do not know how else to handle this.

Comment: The code I provided correctly handles the data as you have provided it, but the more I think about it, the more I think the symptom you show (dates and integers) illustrates some fundamental problem in your spreadsheet: if you have some cells formatted as dates and some not, it will give inconsistent results. Try highlighting everything relevant within the spreadsheet and remove all formatting (in win10/excel, *Home>Editing>Clear>Clear Formats*). You'll see what Excel thought were dates shift to integers, everything remaining is unrecognized, meaning you need to normalize things.

Comment: One possibility is that you learn what format Excel expects for dates and change all values to this format. For mine, it expects `yyyy-mm-dd`, anything else is a verbatim string. Another possibility is that you tell Excel to never try to do anything by converting the format from "Generic" to "Text", and then export it. You may need to back-convert your integers back to "Date", them copy/paste as strings to force it to be Text ... and then use R to read the data again. Bottom line, you have mixed formats that are being stored in different ways. (Excel thinks it's helping you ...)

Comment: @r2evans, thank you so much my friend. This solved the problem.

Comment: updated/fixed, thanks @MrFlick