# Converting a date in R returns NA

Tags: r

| date |
| --- |
| 05-06-2016 |
| 05-07-2016 |
| 4/13/2016 |
| 4/14/2016 |

I want to format the column to date format using below code

```r
td3 <- read.csv("Book2.csv")
td3$date <- as.Date(td3$date, "%m-%d-%y")
```

when i run the code the last 2 rows return NA

Comment: That is because the last two rows are not of order `%m-%d-%y`

Comment: Take a look at `anytime`, which is more flexible.

Comment: If your data only varies on the use of `-` versus `/`, then I suggest that onyambu's answer is the clearest. Otherwise, if it can vary in other ways (e.g., m-d-y vs d-m-y), then this is a duplicate, where https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319606/3358272 provides resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 as.Date.character(gsub("/", "-",td3$date), '%m-%d-%Y')
[1] "2016-05-06" "2016-05-07" "2016-04-13" "2016-04-14"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
as.Date(parse_date_time(df$date, orders = c('mdy', 'dmy')))

[1] "2016-05-06" "2016-05-07" "2016-04-13" "2016-04-14"
```