# Converting Date Column from "YYYYMMDD" and "DD-MMM-YY" to "DD/MM/YYYY"

Tags: r, date, format

I have a date column that has a combination of the two following date types: "YYYYMMDD" and "DD-MMM-YY" I am wanting to convert the column to a "DD/MM/YYYY". Below is an example of what it looks like:

```
Birth_Day|
20021019 |
20021024 |
24-Oct-02|
26-Oct-02|
```

I am wanting to convert it to:

```
Birth_Day |
19/10/2002|
24/10/2002|
24/10/2002|
26/10/2002|
```

Comment: If you need it to still be a `Date` object (i.e., number-like math still works), then you cannot convert it to `"19/10/2002"`. However, if this is for reporting, see `format(x$Birth_Day, format="%d/%m/%Y")` where the `%`-codes are listed in `?strptime`.

Comment: But for converting from your disparate dataset, you need something a bit more adaptive (and likely ***inferential***, since 2-digit years, especially in the 01-31 range, are problematic). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319606/3358272.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `parse_date` with `format`

```
library(parsedate)
df1$Birth_Day <- format(parse_date(df1$Birth_Day), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

-output

```
> df1
   Birth_Day
1 19/10/2002
2 24/10/2002
3 24/10/2002
4 26/10/2002
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Birth_Day = c("20021019", "20021024", "24-Oct-02", 
"26-Oct-02")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```