# Character date variable with various format outputs - "R"

Tags: r, date

I am using "R" and am hoping someone can assist with my date formatting issue. I have a character variable from a dataset that I Imported from Excel.

```
DateVar <- c("12-07-2017", "43229", "43137", "03-27-2018")
```

The excel file I am using has two date formats in the same variable (MM-DD-YYYY and YYYY-MM-DD), hence the two formats in "DateVar". The date formatted YYYY-MM-DD converts to the excel date (i.e 43229).

I would like to have all the values be the same date format (ideally YYYY-MM-DD), but I am having issues converting them consistently.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an indicator vector for the observations that have been converted wrongly:

```
indicator <- !grepl("-", DateVar)
```

Then you can use this vector to convert these dates using the answer from this - [How to convert Excel date format to proper date with Lubridate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-with-lubridate)
.

Comment: Interesting. So if I wanted to now apply the as.date function from the link you provided, how would I do that to only the indicator values that resulted in "TRUE"?