# How do you change numerical values in R into dates?

Tags: r, numbers

Hi this question has been bugging me for some time.

So I am trying to convert the so-called dates in my R project into actual dates. Right now the dates are arranged in a numerical manner, ie after 2/28/2020 it's not 3/1/2020 but 2/3/2020.

I've tried the

```
as.Date(3/14/2020, origin = "14-03-2020")
```

and also

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("10/9/2009 0:00:00", "10/15/2009 0:00:00"))
 as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

and

```
 strDates <- c("01/28/2020", "05/03/2020")%>%
  dates <- as.Date(strDates, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

i just plugged in two dates to test out if it works or not because there are about around 40 dates. However, my output is as follows:

```
Error in as.Date.default(., 3/14/2020, origin = "14-03-2020") : do not know how to convert '.' to class “Date”
```

for the first one and then

the second one is:

```
data frame not found
```

the third one is

```
Error in as.Date(strDates, "%m/%d/%Y") : object 'strDates' not found
```

Comment: Some of that is not legal or realistic code. For instance, in `as.Date(3/14/2020)`, that's replacing your `3/14/2020/` with `0.000106082`, because that's what 3 divided by 14 divided by 2020 resolves to. You need to identify it as a string with single- or double-quotes, as in `as.Date("3/14/2020")`. The second problem there is that your origin needs to be unambiguous to R, so `origin="2020-03-14"`, as shown in the examples in [`?as.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/as.Date.html).

Comment: The error about converting "." to a date is because you have `c(...) %>% dates <- as.Date(...)`, which is just confused code. The `%>%` is injecting the `.` as the first argument of the next command, effectively making it `as.Date(., strDates, "%m/%d'%Y")`, which is obviously not what you intended. Remove the `%>%` and try that part again.

Comment: Lastly, you have some really confused standards on format here. You start using `origin="14-03-2020"` which suggests `"%d-%m-%Y"`, but then you later reference `"%m/%d/%Y"` (which appears to be more appropriate given some of the strings you have provided).

Comment: Post-lastly ... you use `origin=` when you provide a numeric date. Use `format=` when you provide a string date. The two generally do not cross.

Comment: `as.Date("3/14/2020", format = "%m/%d/%Y")` and `as.Date(c("01/28/2020", "05/03/2020"), format = "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: @r2evans Combine your comments to one answer. It's quite useful for learning the use of `as.Date` and formatting dates. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Issues with your code:

1. `as.Date(3/14/2020, origin = "14-03-2020")`

   First, R will replace `3/14/2020` with `0.000106082`, since that's what 3 divided by 14 divided by 2020 equals. You need to identify it as a string using single or double quotes, as in: `as.Date("3/14/2020", origin = "14-03-2020")`.
2. But that is still broken. When converting to `Date`, if you provide a `character` (string) input, then you *may* need to provide `format=`, since it needs to know which numbers in the string correspond to year, month, date, etc. If you provide a `numeric` (or `integer`) input, then you *do* need to provide `origin=`, so that it knows what "day 0" is. For unix, epoch is what you need, so `origin="1970-01-01"`. If you're using dates from Excel, you need `origin="1899-12-30"` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230524).
3. Your next error is because you are mixing magrittr ops with ... base R.

   ```r
    strDates <- c("01/28/2020", "05/03/2020")%>%
     dates <- as.Date(strDates, "%m/%d/%Y")
   ```

   The issue here has nothing to do with dates. The use of `%>%` on line 1 is taking the output of line 1 (in R, assignment to a variable invisibly returns the assigned numbers, which is why chaining assignment works, `a <- b <- 2`) and injecting it as the first argument in the next function call. With this your code was eventually interpreted as

   ```r
    strDates <- c("01/28/2020", "05/03/2020")%>%
      { dates <- as.Date(., strDates, "%m/%d/%Y") }
   ```

   which is obviously not what you intended or need. I suspect that this is just an artifact of getting frustrated and was mid-stage converting from a `%>%` pipe to something else, and you forgot to clean up the `%>%`s. This could be

   ```r
   dates <- c("01/28/2020", "05/03/2020") %>%
     as.Date("%m/%d/%Y")
   dates
   # [1] "2020-01-28" "2020-05-03"
   ```
4. Your data.frame code seems to work fine, though you do not assign the new `Date`-assigned values back to the frame. Try this slight adaptation:

   ```r
   df <- data.frame(Date = c("10/9/2009 0:00:00", "10/15/2009 0:00:00"))
   df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
   df
   #         Date
   # 1 2009-10-09
   # 2 2009-10-15
   str(df)
   # 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
   #  $ Date: Date, format: "2009-10-09" "2009-10-15"
   ```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. 1. oh I see I am going to change it to 4 now. I just tried and it works perfectly for 4 but there is only a minor issue left: it shows the list of date in the correct format in another chart data_frame. I just want to ask how I can incorporate it to my actual data set to create a graph. Thank you very much for the update, I have just used it for a week or so, so this helps a lot and I have learnt so much.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. `data_frame`? graph? None of that was included in the question. `Date` objects can be plotted just like any `numeric` or `integer`.

Comment: I am sorry for not giving enough information. I mean I have a certain data set containing the messy dates and now that I have created a data frame for dates, how do I incorporate it into the original data set? Merge(RKI_COVID19_200504, date = dt?) the RKI_COVID19_200504 is the file name. Thanks again. Really helps a lot.