# Excel Date-Timestamp getting Changed when importing to R. how to change it to timestamp in R?

Tags: r, timestamp

Date Column in Excel

```
       Date
2021-02-19 10:05:03
2021-02-19 09:47:19
2021-02-19 10:53:19
```

Date column importing in R

```
     Date
44245.5487615741 
44245.6650578704 
4246.42021990744
```

How do I change this date back in timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it would be good to know how you load the data.
For converting the Excel number to date this might help you [How to convert Excel date format to proper date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-in-r/62334132)

If you use `openxlsx::read.xlsx()` you probably want to use the `detectDates` parameter.