# as.Date will not retain dates from my raw data

Tags: r, date, as.date

I'm using as.Date for a dataset I have with dates as a variable that I'm using on the x axis of a graph. I had everything fine and the graph output was great, but something happened and now there are missing dates and formatting with things like %Y and %d aren't working!

Can someone please help me figure out how to get the data to feed in correctly?

```
IHS <- read.csv("IHS 20-21.csv")
IHS$Start.Date <- as.Date(IHS$Start.Date)
```

This is the code I'm using. If you need more info I can share more, not sure what bits of code would be helpful here, but these two lines are where the problem is. If I feed in the data and check the environment the table looks fine. But then when I add in the as.Date it starts to lose dates.

The dates are in an excel column as follows:
[excel dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KEMg.png)

And I'm trying to get the dates in YYYY/MM/DD format, but I'll be happy with any format as long as the data is all there!

Comment: `as.Date(IHS$Start.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` _might_ work.  But it might not depending on if what is seen in your image is the raw value or if it is a mask on top of something else.  We could answer with more certainty if you could show us the result of `dput(head(IHS$Start.Date))`.

Comment: Thank you, when I used the code dput(head(IHS$Start.Date)) this is the output: 
 structure(c(-715917, NA, NA, -715825, -715613, NA), class = "Date")

Comment: This thread might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230524/10276092

Comment: @M.Viking Thank you, I'm a bit lost of what the thread is talking about as an origin? Would that be the first date in the excel sheet column?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments where the structure is listed as c(-715917, NA, NA, -715825, -715613, NA), it looks to me like your dates came in as unix epoch time referenced to origin 1-1-1970. You can use `lubridate` to convert.

Example:

```
library(lubridate)
lubridate::as_date(c(-715917, NA, NA, -715825, -715613, NA))

[1] "9-11-20"  NA         NA         "10-02-20" "10-09-20" NA
```

To structure YYYY-MM-DD use `ymd()`:

```
library(lubridate)
IHS$Start.Date <- ymd(as_date(c(-715917, NA, NA, -715825, -715613, NA)))
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html