# How to deal with complex date format when importing dataframe from an excel file R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following column that I am importing from a an excel file.

```
dates <- structure(list(ServiceDate = c("44433", "44497", "44400", "44513", 
"44501", "44398", "44501", "44496", "44432", "44513", "44389", 
"44513", "44515", "44513", "44515", "NULL", "44501", "44432", 
"44512", "44470")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But when I try to do some of the more traditional date convsertions I can't get the format to be correct.

```
anydate(date$ServiceDate)
 [1] "4443-01-01" "4449-01-01" "4440-01-01" "4451-01-01" "4450-01-01" "4439-01-01" "4450-01-01" "4449-01-01" "4443-01-01" "4451-01-01" "4438-01-01"
[12] "4451-01-01" "4451-01-01" "4451-01-01" "4451-01-01" NA           "4450-01-01" "4443-01-01" "4451-01-01" "4447-01-01"
```

I know I can change the format in the actual file but there a lot of files like this and I need the solution to be in code.

Here is my desired output

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230524/12993861 for an solutioin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is excel date, convert to numeric, and use `as_date` with `origin`

```
library(lubridate)
as_date(as.numeric(dates$ServiceDate), origin = '1899-12-30')
```

---

Or another way is

```
openxlsx::convertToDate(dates$ServiceDate)
```