# Reference the column from a dataframe in a list during a for loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I am facing some difficulties with filtering a dataframe in a loop.

I am copying data from an Excel file, putting everything in a list of data frames. I am trying to do some cleanup and the 8th column (.periodenddate) contains some dates. But there is some string starting by "Unable...". So I was trying to take out those rows to be able to convert the numbers into dates. Being from Excel, they look like "43890" at the moment.

I did find a way to make it work at the end of the code when I taking the data frame out of the list but ideally I would keep it inside the list to loop through it.

Also, I can not share the file unfortunately but it is simply Excel file with 15 sheets with the following columns: ISIN, MAIN, .Date, .Calcdate, .brokername, .fperiod, .rfperiod, .periodenddate, .analystcode, .analystname

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

myPath <- "MyFile.xlsm"
sheetsName <- excel_sheets(myPath)

for(a in 1:length(sheetsName)){
  if (!(sheetsName[[a]] %in% c("Isin&Date", "Parameters", "TempSheet","Unique ISIN"))){
    assign(paste0("DT_", sheetsName[[a]]), read_excel(myPath,a))
  }
}

FY <- list() #Was not sure how to make this part cleaner
FY[[1]] <- rbind(`DT_Output FY-1(1)`,`DT_Output FY-1(2)`)
FY[[2]] <- rbind(`DT_Output FY-2(1)`,`DT_Output FY-2(prev)`)
FY[[3]] <- rbind(`DT_Output FY-3(1)`,`DT_Output FY-3(2)`)
FY[[4]] <- rbind(`DT_Output FY-4(1)`,`DT_Output FY-4(2)`,`DT_Output FY-4(prev)`)
FY[[5]] <- rbind(`DT_Output FY-5(1)`,`DT_Output FY-5(2)`)
FY[[6]] <- rbind(`DT_Output FY-6(1)`,`DT_Output FY-6(prev)`)
FY[[7]] <- rbind(`DT_Output FY-7(1)`,`DT_Output FY-7(2)`)
FY[[8]] <- rbind(`DT_Output FY-8(1)`,`DT_Output FY-8(prev)`)

rm(list=setdiff(ls(),"FY"))

for (a in 1:length(FY)){
  FY[[a]] <- subset(FY[[a]],FY[[a]]$MAIN!="NULL")
  FY[[a]] <- distinct(FY[[a]])
  FY[[a]] <- FY[[a]] %>% #part that does not work
    filter(!grepl('able', FY[[a]][8]))
}

#Thing that works:
FYTest <- FY[[1]]
FYTest <- FYTest %>% 
  filter(!grepl('able', FYTest$.periodenddate))
```

Also class(FY[[1]][8]) gives the following results:
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

**EDIT:**

Code that worked:

```
FY <- excel_sheets(myPath) %>% 
  setdiff(c("Isin&Date", "Parameters", "TempSheet","Unique ISIN")) %>% 
  map(read_excel, path = myPath) %>% 
  bind_rows()

colnames(FY)<- c("ISIN","estEPS","date","calcDate","broker","fPeriod","rfPeriod","periodEnd","analystCode","anlystName")

FY <- FY %>% 
  subset(.,estEPS!="NULL" & periodEnd!="NULL" & !str_detect(periodEnd, "field")) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(., periodEnd = as.Date(as.numeric(periodEnd), origin = "1899-12-30"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what your excel sheets are like or what you're trying to do, but it might be easier to load them all like this:

```
FY <- excel_sheets(myPath) %>% 
    setdiff(c("Isin&Date", "Parameters", "TempSheet","Unique ISIN")) %>% 
    map(read_excel, path = myPath) %>% 
    bind_rows()
```

This will give you one tibble with all of the data.  Then you can filter out or fix the offending rows.  After you've done that, you can `mutate` to convert the dates.  As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230524/12744323), you can use `as.Date(43890, origin = "1899-12-30")` to convert the dates.

Comment: I guess coming from the sheets in Excel I wanted to keep a similar structure and create one data frame per sheet which is a mistake.

I will update my initial question to show the code I ended up using, thank you!