# Any R function to solve this dates problem?

Tags: r

I have this column is date of birth. Is there any R function or any method to solve this date problem, the dates in Excel are ok. But when I read the file in R I am getting wrong dates as below:

```
2047-11-03

2064-06-08

1098639-10-01

377383-01-18

1979098-01-27

-177103-09-27

-186092-08-24

1612569600

-236822400
```

the original dates in excel as below

01/11/1977

07/06/1994

11/09/1982

07/05/1974

19/11/1992

06/12/1967

29/10/1967

06/02/2021

01/07/1962

I used the following to imports the data
df<- import_list("df.xlsx")

Comment: Can you post the true dates corresponding to those values in the question, please? How are you reading the files? Please post the code producing those results. And see if [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-in-r) solves the problem.

Comment: Could you try to import this data table with either the command `df <- openxlsx::read.xlsx("df.xlsx")` or `df <- readxl::read_excel("df.xlsx")`?

Comment: This seems like your "ok dates" in excel are in a weird format, perhaps they are only okay on the surface, but not at cell level.

Comment: Please note that my data is multiple excel sheets, that why i used the import_list ()

Comment: please add a sample excel file to make the problem reproducible..

Comment: `readxl::read_xlsx()` didn't seem to have any difficulty in parsing the dates. You can read a list of files by mapping the list onto read_xlsx. Something like `map(file_list, read_xlsx)`

Comment: Thanks for all, the problem solved:
 
the problem was in reading using import_list().
i used the following:

sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(path)
df <- lapply(sheets,readxl::read_excel, path=path) 
names(df) <- sheets

Comment: That seems surprising to me. I think `rio::import_list('x.xlsx')` actually calls `readxl::read_xlsx('x.xslx')` under the hood so I would have expected the same results. But glad you solved your problem anyhow.