# Excel date format not imported correctly into R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, import

I am importing an Excel file into R, where the date format in Excel is "27-02-2012".
However, once I import the dataset into R with the code below:

```
#Loading packages
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(stringr)
library(textclean)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
```

import data

```
data_corpus <- read_excel("data.xlsx",
                                   sheet= "xyz")
```

The date format in some rows stays as "27-02-2012", while other rows look as follows "40911".

Is it possible to convert all values under the "date" column to have the following format:
"27-02-2012"?

Here is a data exmaple:

```
sapply(data_corpus, class)
```

output:

```
   post                      date                  
  "character"               "character"
```

I have tried the following code, but it turns all values in "date" into NAs:

```
data_corpus$date <- as_date(data_corpus$date)
```

Sample:

```
data_corpus$post[2]
[1] this is really unfortunateا"
> data_corpus$date[2]
[1] "27-02-2012"
```

Comment: Potential duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-in-r

Comment: It looks like the "date" column in Excel is a mixture of dates and character strings representing dates.  It might be easier to edit the Excel file to ensure the whole column is in the same format. In R you will have to separate the numbers from the strings and follow the link in the previous comment to covert the number and read the documentation for `as.Date()` & `strptime()` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `col_types` parameter

```
data_corpus <- read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet= "xyz", col_types = c("text", "date"))
```