# Character to Date

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate, chr

I am having some problems with changing dates from Excel (characters in R) into date in R.

Knowing that I am using : `as.Date(Data$Datum, "d%/m%/y%")`
But it returns `NA NA NA`..

And the date starts in Excel on : **1-1-2019** , but in R it shows : **"43466"**

I have tried also **lubridate** : `dmy(Data$Datum)` , but it also returns all the values as **NA**.

Could you please help me with this situation!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you're getting the underlying Excel representation of a date. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43230470/4550695 for potential solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this part and everything will be ok,

```
date <- as.Date(Data$Datum, "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Place the % sign in front and use Y not y because it is 2019 and not 19.

Finally, separate mdY with "-"