# how to load dates in a readable format from excel into r?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, date, format

I have an excel spreadsheet that has different date formats. R reads in the dates correctly when they're formatted as m/dd/yy, but when they're m/d/yy, it reads them as a code like this: 36251.

To fix it, I found this, which seems useful, but it is only for one date and I have multiple.

[How to convert Excel date format to proper date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-in-r)

This was what was suggested:

```
as.Date(42705, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

So I tried this:

```
stockindices0$Date <- as.Date(stockindices0$Date , origin = "12-30-99")
```

but got the error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I also tried it with the year as 1899 with no success.

Comment: Have you tried just changing the date format in excel?

Comment: You can highlight the column, click format cells, click custom, in the "type" box write m/dd/yy

Comment: My teacher wants everything done in R :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
as.Date(stockindices0$Date, format = "%d/%m/%y")
```