# How to change a number into datetime format in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have a vector `a = 40208.64507`.

In excel, I can automatically change `a` to a datetime: `2010/1/30  15:28:54` by click the Date type.

I tried some methods but I cannot get the same result in R, just as in excel.

```
a = 40208.64507
# in Excel, a can change into: 2010/1/30  15:28:54

as.Date(a, origin = "1899-12-30")
lubridate::as_datetime(a, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

**Is there any way to get the same results in R as in Excel?**

Comment: If I put that number into Excel, I get 30th January 2010, which is the same result I get in R. Also, if you look at the decimal part (0.64507), this should not be 5:31:12 in any date-time system I know of. Are you sure you have the correct number here?

Comment: Try `openxlsx::convertToDateTime(a)`, taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62334132/8245406).

Comment: @ Allan, I apologize for my mistake and I have corrected the data. The result in Excel should be 2010/1/30 15:28:54.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are several ways.  chron class is the closest to Excel in terms of internal representations -- they are the same except for origin -- and the simplest so we list that one first.   We also show how to use chron as an intermediate step to get POSIXct.

Base R provides an approach which avoids package dependencies and lubridate might be used if you are already using it.

**1)** Add the appropriate origin using chron to get a chron datetime or convert that to POSIXct.  Like Excel, chron works in days and fractions of a day, but chron uses the UNIX Epoch as origin whereas Excel uses the one shown below.

```
library(chron)

a <- 40208.64507

# chron date/time
ch <- as.chron("1899-12-30") + a; ch
## [1] (01/30/10 15:28:54)

# POSIXct date/time in local time zone
ct <- as.POSIXct(ch); ct
## [1] "2010-01-30 10:28:54 EST"

# POSIXct date/time in UTC
as.POSIXct(format(ct), tz = "UTC")
## [1] "2010-01-30 10:28:54 UTC"
```

**2)** Using only base R convert the number to Date class using the indicated origin and then to POSIXct.

```
# POSIXct with local time zone
ct <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(a, origin = "1899-12-30")); ct
## [1] "2010-01-30 10:28:54 EST"

# POSIXct with UTC time zone
as.POSIXct(format(ct), tz = "UTC")
## [1] "2010-01-30 15:28:54 UTC"
```

**3)** Using lubridate it is similar to base R so we can write

```
library(lubridate)

# local time zone
as_datetime(as_date(a, origin = "1899-12-30"), tz = "")
[1] "2010-01-30 15:28:54 EST"

# UTC time zone
as_datetime(as_date(a, origin = "1899-12-30"))
[1] "2010-01-30 15:28:54 UTC"
```