# How to use r to match and index data from an excel table into a different excel table?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, match, vlookup

1

I have two different excel spreadsheets (input and output files). Instead of using the "match" and "index" functions directly in excel, I would like to use a r script to look up for the values in my matrix in the input file and store the values in the correct cell in my output file.

My input file consists of a matrix (columns and rows) and my output file, too. However,the data in the output is structured differently. A simple transposition does not work here. Apart from that, I may have additional countries in my output file which are not listed in my input file and vice versa. Hence, I need to use a two-dimensional lookup to find the values in the input file and store them in my output file, accordingly.

Suppose this this my input file (fictitious numbers for illustration):
[image]

This is my output file with a fixed data structure which I would like not to change:
[image]

This is my r code:

```
#clearing workspace
rm(list=ls())

# Load required libraries
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

# get username 
username <- Sys.getenv("USER")

# Load input and output Excel files
input_file <- paste0("/Users/", username, "/Downloads/input_file.xlsx", collapse = "")
output_file <- paste0("/Users/", username, "/Desktop/output_file.xlsx", collapse = "")

# Load the input and output matrices
input_matrix <- read_xlsx(input_file, sheet = "KLICKHERE")
output_matrix <- read_xlsx(output_file, sheet = "ENTERHERE")

input_matrix |>
  mutate(quarter = as.Date(quarter)) |>
  pivot_longer(-quarter, names_to = "country", values_to = "value") |>
  mutate(country = ifelse(str_detect(country, "UK"), "UK", str_to_title(country))) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = "quarter", values_from = "value", values_fn = ~paste0(.x, collapse = ",")) |>
  write_csv("output.csv")
```

However, this code simply transposes the matrix in my input file, does not look up in a two dimensional way for the values and store them in the correct cells in my output file. If no value is available in the input file, it should just leave the cell in the output file empty.
How do I manage to do this in r?
Thanks for your support.

```
> dput(input_matrix)
structure(list(quarter = structure(c(1640995200, 1648771200, 
1656633600, 1664582400, 1672531200, 1680307200, 1688169600, 1696118400, 
1704067200, 1711929600, 1719792000, 1727740800, 1735689600, 1743465600, 
1751328000, 1759276800, 1767225600, 1775001600, 1782864000, 1790812800, 
1798761600, 1806537600, 1814400000, 1822348800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), USA = c(3.2, 1.2617029893181, 2.60440314593473, 
0.205747170894448, 2.99742239259666, 0.454981287908458, 0.812500920203167, 
3.53979030628357, 2.203045423758, 0.054471200265702, 2.92803826928382, 
0.718964340034683, 1.60951470750129, 5.07871970749977, 5.69403126006479, 
1.22925310502368, 3.66396581660635, 2.37878419177338, 2.29467033332622, 
5.03595630837856, 2.25374064291613, 1.69444882698869, 4.16205429572283, 
4.50132478373478), Switzerland = c(4, 2.38038947850657, 5.47668679859636, 
5.91361388434538, 4.77394394868853, 0.51390066344242, 5.01921886848812, 
2.50248783131655, 4.01832050488102, 5.41622706832583, 5.30149956216031, 
3.16778787833323, 2.199973116468, 5.01366343788224, 4.29923192879718, 
4.74615956273584, 1.28422990972834, 0.284477581237545, 2.08538425170424, 
0.463401565316672, 5.19591972413863, 1.48139690105528, 3.72116283773825, 
2.88215533537597), China = c(-1, 3.35979319893751, 3.41085866605616, 
0.560088392935827, 5.13880709708747, 4.12321867925324, 0.678575131657537, 
5.05445686032681, 1.91810878862458, 1.3819304062605, 0.80241487254838, 
5.88840619656107, 1.4643177661779, 1.30971606465739, 5.27065656469845, 
2.59430512488464, 2.43626303990699, 2.6781401256743, 2.92798363758913, 
3.82250194049481, 3.53273150832144, 2.88313585242345, 2.2629948322944, 
1.45945340574197)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
>
```

```
> dput(output_matrix)
structure(list(...1 = c("Portugal", "USA", "South Africa", "Switzerland", 
"China"), `44562` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `44927` = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `45017` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `45383` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `45474` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `45658` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `45748` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `45839` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `45931` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `46388` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `46478` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `46569` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `46661` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a straight-forward double-pivot:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
input_matrix %>%
  mutate(quarter = as.Date(quarter)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -quarter, names_to = "country") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = country, names_from = "quarter", values_from = "value")
# # A tibble: 3 × 25
#   country    `2022-01-01` `2022-04-01` `2022-07-01` `2022-10-01` `2023-01-01` `2023-04-01` `2023-07-01` `2023-10-01`
#   <chr>             <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 USA                 3.2         1.26         2.60        0.206         3.00        0.455        0.813         3.54
# 2 Switzerla…          4           2.38         5.48        5.91          4.77        0.514        5.02          2.50
# 3 China              -1           3.36         3.41        0.560         5.14        4.12         0.679         5.05
# # ℹ 16 more variables: `2024-01-01` <dbl>, `2024-04-01` <dbl>, `2024-07-01` <dbl>, `2024-10-01` <dbl>,
# #   `2025-01-01` <dbl>, `2025-04-01` <dbl>, `2025-07-01` <dbl>, `2025-10-01` <dbl>, `2026-01-01` <dbl>,
# #   `2026-04-01` <dbl>, `2026-07-01` <dbl>, `2026-10-01` <dbl>, `2027-01-01` <dbl>, `2027-04-01` <dbl>,
# #   `2027-07-01` <dbl>, `2027-10-01` <dbl>
```

If you need to have the names be what appear to be Excel date-numbers (e.g., `44562`), we can reference [How to convert Excel date format to proper date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-in-r) to convert them using `"1899-12-30"`:

```r
input_matrix %>%
  mutate(quarter = as.Date(quarter) - as.Date("1899-12-30")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -quarter, names_to = "country") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = country, names_from = "quarter", values_from = "value")
# # A tibble: 3 × 25
#   country    `44562` `44652` `44743` `44835` `44927` `45017` `45108` `45200` `45292` `45383` `45474` `45566` `45658`
#   <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 USA            3.2    1.26    2.60   0.206    3.00   0.455   0.813    3.54    2.20  0.0545   2.93    0.719    1.61
# 2 Switzerla…     4      2.38    5.48   5.91     4.77   0.514   5.02     2.50    4.02  5.42     5.30    3.17     2.20
# 3 China         -1      3.36    3.41   0.560    5.14   4.12    0.679    5.05    1.92  1.38     0.802   5.89     1.46
# # ℹ 11 more variables: `45748` <dbl>, `45839` <dbl>, `45931` <dbl>, `46023` <dbl>, `46113` <dbl>, `46204` <dbl>,
# #   `46296` <dbl>, `46388` <dbl>, `46478` <dbl>, `46569` <dbl>, `46661` <dbl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and code suggestion. Do you happen to know if there is a way to store the values in the correct cells in the excel output file instead of just transposing the input matrix?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Your `output_matrix` is the simple-transposition, and I thought that's what you wanted. This does it programmatically, though perhaps `t(..)` and some data repair could do the same (several assumptions here).

Comment: My output_matrix just happens to be a simple transposition of my input_matrix but this does not have to be the case, in general. That's why I need a two-way lookup.