# Excel spreadsheet date column headings imported as character format

Tags: r, readxl, as.date

My excel spreadsheet always imports to R with column headings like "44983" rather than the d/m/y format that I want. I want to fix this in R rather than in excel.
My dataframe is called "backlog" and has 95 columns, the first one is 'Backlog 62d+' and the rest of the columns are these dates like "44983" which R has registered as characters.

I've tried the following code, but my dataframe still looks the same - the column headings haven't changed to date d/m/y format.

```
backlog <- read_excel("./Weekly/Weekly_Cancer_62d_PTL_Tracker.xlsx", 
                                                sheet = "Provider Trends", range = "B24:CR44" %>% setNames(., c('Backlog 62d+', format(as.Date(as.numeric(names(.)[-1]), origin = '1899-12-30'), '%m/%d/%Y'))))
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230470/how-to-convert-excel-date-format-to-proper-date-in-r  You simply need to transform it **after** importing the data

Comment: I did try this one, but couldn't figure out how to get it to apply to multiple columns: this code `backlog[,2:95] <- as.Date(backlog[,2:95], origin = "1899-12-30")` gave me the follow error:
`Error in as.Date.default(backlog[, 2:95], origin = "1899-12-30") : 
  do not know how to convert 'backlog[, 2:95]' to class “Date”`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, I believe this is what you are looking for, with a few transformations :

```r
vector_column_number <- colnames(backlog)[-1] # Names of your columns without the first one
list_columns_numeric <- lapply(vector_column_number , as.numeric) # Transformation of the list of character to a list of numeric (needed for as.Date)
list_columns_date <- lapply(list_columns_numeric , as.Date, origin = "1899-12-30") # Transformation of the numerical value to the date value 
vector_columns_character <- lapply(list_columns_date , as.character) |> unlist() # Tranformation back to a vector of character
colnames(backlog) <- c(colnames(backlog)[1],vector_columns_character ) # Change the columns' names, keeping the first one and using the vector created before
```

Comment: I get the following error with the second line of that code - any ideas why? `Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: Please check the edited answer, it would be easier if, for your next question on SO, you provide a reproductible example, see : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example